# How to identify uploading item is folder while doing drag and drop

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I am using file upload functionality using drag and upload .I want to identify uploading item is folder.Is there any possible way to identify uploading item is folder for IE browser in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the (pretty experimental) directory API:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/dev-guide/html5/folder-upload/

Basically, you need to check:

```
event.dataTransfer.items[0].webkitGetAsEntry().isDirectory
                  //     ↑ You may need a loop here
```

Comment: I think this should work but I want get length of items using e.dataTransfer.items.length but getting items is undefined or null error